# what is the meaning/output of this piece of MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, matrix

Can someone explain to me the meaning/significance of this code line by line? I am a beginner in MATLAB/programming so please use simple terminology particularly when explaining the fprintf function. (I tried to use the 'help' function in MATLAB to understand the 'fprintf' function and I still dont understand it... also if its simple enough, what is the expected output?

```
A = zeros(1,3); %pre-allocate space 
k = 1;  %count loop iterations 
valueMatrix = [1 2 3; 5 6 7]; 
for jj = valueMatrix 
fprintf('iteration %d:\n', k)
A(k) = jj(1) + jj(2);
jj, A  %display variables on terminal 
k = k + 1; 
end
```

Comment: Why not run it and see?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Let's go through each line of code separately.  Bear in mind that I'm answering mainly because the `for` loop uses a **matrix** instead of a vector, and not many people know what that actually does.

---

```
A = zeros(1,3); %pre-allocate space
```

This creates an empty vector of three elements and this is stored in `A`.

---

```
k = 1;  %count loop iterations
```

This I will explain later.

---

```
valueMatrix = [1 2 3; 5 6 7];
```

Declare a matrix of size 2 x 3, which looks like this:

```
1   2   3
5   6   7
```

---

```
for jj = valueMatrix
```

This is a `for` loop.  I'm assuming you know what that is.  `for` loops allow you to execute a piece of code inside the `for` syntax a given number of times.  You specify a vector or a matrix and the loop executes the piece of code within the `for` construct again and again... and each time it executes, it pulls each value from the vector or matrix and stores it into a loop counter variable.  In this case, that variable is `jj`.  For example, if we did this:

```
for jj = 1 : 8
    disp(jj);
end
```

This loop will start with `jj = 1`, and we will display this in the console.  Next, we go `jj = 2` and we display this in the console and we will keep going until `jj = 8` then we stop.  Now with a **matrix** this is slightly different.  How it works is that at each iteration, we pull out a **column** at a time.  For example, if we did:

```
for jj = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
    disp(jj);
end
```

We would display:

```
1
4
7
```

... at the first iteration, then:

```
2
5
8
```

... then finally at the last iteration:

```
3
6
9
```

As such, if we did:

```
for jj = valueMatrix
```

... this means that we will run this loop **three** times.  At the first iteration, `jj` would be:

```
1
5
```

The next iteration:

```
2
6
```

The last iteration:

```
3
7
```

What's important is that at each iteration, `jj` is a 2 element vector.

---

```
    fprintf('iteration %d:\n', k)
```

`fprintf` stands for **formatted** print to **file**.  However, the way it is being called prints to the screen instead of a text file.  This may look unfamiliar to you because this is essentially the same way you'd call `printf` in C.  The first parameter to this function is a string that you want to display to the screen.  What you can also do is display the contents of a variable by putting the right specifiers inside the string.  You use what are known as **formatting strings**.  In this case, `%d` specifies an integer you want to print out, and `\n` means to move to the next line.  Each formatting string is accompanied by the variable you want to print.  In our case, `%d` is paired with the variable `k`, so you want to print out the variable `k` at each iteration.  It would look like this at each iteration:

```
iteration 1:
iteration 2:
iteration 3:
```

---

```
    A(k) = jj(1) + jj(2);
```

You'll notice that `k` starts at 1 and increments by 1 each time the loop iterates (the `k = k + 1` statement two lines later).  Therefore, at each iteration, we populate each entry in `A` with the addition of the two elements in `jj`.

---

```
    jj, A  %display variables on terminal
```

Self-explanatory.  We show these variables to the screen, on top of the `iteration` print out statements... a bit messy IMHO.

---

```
    k = k + 1;
```

Talked about this already.  Increments at each iteration.

---

```
end
```

End the loop.

---

Therefore, the expected result that the three element vector stored in `A` has its contents changed, where each element sums from a column from `valueMatrix`.  As such, for `A` you should get:

```
A = [6 8 10];
```